# How to get Android layout_weight to work?

Tags: android-layout, android-layout-weight

I'm so frustrated with Android's layout scaling/positioning. I can't get the OS to properly "weigh" my layouts. The base layout is a LinearLayout, and the child layouts have weights set correctly. But when it's run, these proportions aren't maintained. Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#38921c">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
```

...(views omitted)

```
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/zero" />

            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/zero" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
```

...(views omitted)

```
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this, the screen (tablet and phone) gives way too much space to the second (0.2 weight) layout, and squeezes the layout(s) below into too small a space. What am I missing regarding proper scaling using layout_weight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_weight` is to specify a size ratio between multiple views.

In this case, it seems you have multiple views. After you have decided how many percentage of the screen supposed to be allocated for each views then you can set it.

**Example:** You want to divide screen into 3 as 2/10, 3/10 and 5/10(half of the screen), then weight in order is 2, 3, 5. (e.g android:layout_weight="2")

**Important:** To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px. Otherwise, all weight measures will be assumed garbage.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but as you can see in my posted code, I've already set the percentages (0.1, 0.2, 0.7), and set the layout_heights to 0. It's not working as advertised.

Comment: instead try using 1, 2, 7 first and there is also something called android:weightSum="" for main layouts. you can see the link with demonstrations: http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/